# revert object and its properties

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object

```
var obj = {
   prop1 : {
      dummy1 : 0,
      dummy2 : 0,
      dummy3 : 0
   },
   prop2 : {
      dummy1 : 0,
      dummy2 : 0,
      dummy3 : 0
   }
};
```

And I need to revert this so that dummy becomes an object and props then becomes it's properties.

So I need my object to look like this

```
var obj = {
    dummy1 : {
        prop1 : 0,
        prop2 : 0   
    },
    dummy2 : {
        prop1 : 0,
        prop2 : 0
    },
    dummy3 : {
        prop1 : 0,
        prop2 : 0
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is achievable with two `for..in` loops

```
var obj = {
        prop1 : {dummy1 : 0, dummy2 : 0, dummy3 : 0},
        prop2 : {dummy1 : 0, dummy2 : 0, dummy3 : 0}
    };
// start of interesting code
var a, b,
    o2 = {};
for (a in obj)
    for (b in obj[a]) {
        if (!o2[b]) o2[b] = {}; // if o2 doesn't have this yet, make new obj
        o2[b][a] = obj[a][b];   // swap
    }
o2; /* {
    "dummy1": {"prop1": 0, "prop2": 0},
    "dummy2": {"prop1": 0, "prop2": 0},
    "dummy3": {"prop1": 0, "prop2": 0}
} */
```

You may also want to check the properties are not inherited, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore has a function for doing something similar to this.  You can use

http://underscorejs.org/#invert

as a starting point.

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L770

```
  _.invert = function(obj) {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in obj) if (_.has(obj, key)) result[obj[key]] = key;
    return result;
  };
```

Comment: sorry i'm not using any libraries, just clean vanilla js :)